# How to multiply total of one column with row entry in SQL ie sum(column_name) * column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Unable to understnad how to use the formula of multiplying total of colum with entry of row.

Tried the code below

```
SELECT g.Item_No, (sum(g.units)* u.Unit_Percentage) as Units@2018Mix
FROM Global_GM_2019 g
FULL JOIN UnitMix_perc_2018 u 
ON u.item_no=g.item_no
GROUP BY g.item_no;
```

I get this eror which I know that should include all the columns in group by function.

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 275
Column 'UnitMix_perc_2018.Unit_Percentage' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Expected

```
Products    units of 2019   % of units of 2018  product mix
a              110                     34            20570
b              120                     23            13915
c              120                     12            7260
d              130                     12            7260
e              125                     23            13915
```

Expected result image added [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC1X1.png)

Comment: Why if you expect that just select 2 columns in the query? What database are you working with?

Comment: Microsoft sql server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

Try computing a summary table and then joining (this will probably run fastest as the join will likely be smaller).

```
Select item_No, unit_sum * Unit_Percentage as Units@2018Mix
From (
  SELECT item_no, sum(g.units) as unit_sum
  FROM Global_GM_2019
  Group by item_no
) as g
  FULL JOIN UnitMix_perc_2018 u 
  ON u.item_no=g.item_no
```

Or simply move the calculation into the sum

```
SELECT g.Item_No, sum(g.units* u.Unit_Percentage) as Units@2018Mix
FROM Global_GM_2019 g
FULL JOIN UnitMix_perc_2018 u 
ON u.item_no=g.item_no
GROUP BY g.item_no;
```

Or add the unit percentage scalar to tour group by.

```
SELECT g.Item_No, (sum(g.units)* u.Unit_Percentage) as Units@2018Mix
FROM Global_GM_2019 g
FULL JOIN UnitMix_perc_2018 u 
ON u.item_no=g.item_no
GROUP BY g.item_no, u.unit_percentage:
```

In reply to the comment stream...
@sag, you are sort of cheating - you are asking two questions in one. The two questions are:

1. I have a syntax error in my posted query. (Saying " I know that should include all the columns in group by function" does not cancel this point out. If you know that, you should do that in your orignal post. Refer to 
   [create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)
2. I'm not going to tell you how it is stored nor how  to calculate it, but I want to get some data from two years in my 4 columns of output.

I have answered question 1 three ways. I can only guess for question 2 (because you provide no details in your question on this subject). Here is my guess.

```
SELECT g.Item_No,
     sum(g19.units),
     (sum(g18.units)* u.Unit_Percentage) as Units@2018Mix,
     /* Maybe */ (sum(g19.units) (double) / sum(g18.units) * 100.0 as g19_pcnt_increase_over_g18  /*???*/
     /* I have no idea how you intend to calculate "product mix" because you provide zero information on this topic. */
FROM Global_GM_2019 g JOIN Global_gm_2018 as G18 on
       g.item_id = g18.item_id
FULL JOIN UnitMix_perc_2018 u 
ON u.item_no=g.item_no
GROUP BY g.item_no, u.unit_percentage:
```

We can only provide answers to the question that you have asked *for which you provide some supporting information*. Again, please refer to how to [create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i Tried 1.query it simply multiplies 2 columns. (incorrect), query 2- does the same, query 3- if i group by unit percentage it just messes up everything and that is incorrect wrt logic

Comment: query one works out the sum of the units for each item_no and multiplies it by the percentage. This is the same formula as your original query except it works out the sum first for each item, then joins to the Unit Mix to multiply by the percentage.

Comment: Query two addresses the missing column in your group by by moving the multiplication into the sum. This should work because (a + b + c) * value is equivalent to (a * value + b * value + c * value) .

Comment: Query 3 works by using your original query and adding the required group by clause for the scalar value unit_percentage (i.e. addressing the original syntax error in your query).

Comment: i want sum of column a* each entry in column B This should be ideally the the answer. If i use sum as mentioned in query 2, it simple multiplies columns in a and columns in b

Comment: I tried query one as well. I am not getting desired output. it is simply multiplying column a and columns b

Comment: I have added some guesses to my question based on what i think you might be trying to ask. However, you do need to add some more information to your question if you want the second part(s) answered

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you really want a `FULL JOIN`, because you will get rows that are `NULL`.

Based on your description, I think you want:

```
SELECT g.Item_No, SUM(g.units * u.Unit_Percentage) as Units_2018Mix
FROM Global_GM_2019 g LEFT JOIN
     UnitMix_perc_2018 u 
     ON u.item_no = g.item_no
GROUP BY g.item_no;
```

In other words, do the multiplication *before* doing the `SUM()`.